# Audit fail "message" bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audit

Please look at the highlighted text.

---

[image]

---

It is apparent that the escape character did not work as intended. Also, I request the reviewers to observe if it is network-wide.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbjvE.png